# SQL-Server drill down in an other table (group by)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, drilldown

OK, I'm quite new to SQL and didn't get to much training!

I'm using SSMS to create stored procedures and open them in Excel.

The code below work just fine, but I need to add a drill down to get more info on some lines.

We need to follow what was invoice and paid on a batch of contracts for our project. Each contract have multiple lines with a description and a couple of other fields(reference, line #, G/L # etc). Plus we have the value of the line, the amount that was invoice for this line and the amount that was paid.

Main table 'CSCOMVTL' have the basic infos including the base value and the invoice amount, but not the paid amount.

'JRAPRVTL' is the list of all invoices with; invoice no., invoice date, invoiced amount and paid amount that we may need to see.

So for each base line, we need a +/- button to show/hide details of the invoice.

Invoice amount and paid amount could be from a rollup, but the number and date won't be on the parent line. If they could be in the same column as other  field not needed it would be great, but I could live with 2 extra columns.

Thanks!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[marpt_qmd_AccPmt_DetailsST]
@contrat varchar(30), @projet varchar(30)

AS
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #RPT
(
    Ligne INT,
    Lien INT,
    Act VARCHAR (10),
    Descr VARCHAR (90),
    MntBase DECIMAL (20,2),
    MntFact DECIMAL (20,2),
    Modif VARCHAR (40),
    Descr3 VARCHAR (90),
    Lien2 INT,
    MntPy DECIMAL (20,2) default '0',


)

INSERT INTO #RPT (Ligne, Lien, Act, Descr, MntBase, MntFact)
SELECT ROW, DETAILCHANGEORDERCOU, ACTIVITY, DESCRIPTION, AMOUNT, INVOICE
FROM cscomvtl
WHERE PROJECTNUMBER = @projet
and LTRIM(RTRIM(PONUMBER)) = @contrat

UPDATE #RPT
SET Modif=m.CHANGEORDERNUMBER, Descr3=m.DESCRIPTION, Lien2=m.CHANGEORDERCOUNTER
FROM cscomac m, #RPT r
where m.COUNTER=r.Lien

UPDATE #RPT
SET MntPy=payment
FROM #RPT r, (select POLINE, sum(payment) payment from jraprvtl where PROJECTNO=@projet
and LTRIM(RTRIM(PURCHASEORDER))=@contrat group by POLINE) d
where r.Ligne=d. POLINE

SELECT 
    Ligne as 'Ligne',
    Act as 'Act.',
    Descr as 'Description 1',
    MntBase as '$ Base',
    MntFact as '$ Invoiced',
    Modif as 'Num. Modif.',
    Descr3 as 'Description 2',
    MntPy as '$ Paid'
    FROM #RPT
    Order by Ligne


Drop table #RPT
```

Comment: Hi @Luskar.  You may find you get more helpful answers if you post what you have tried so far, including a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

First off, take the time & learn SQL.  It's an invaluable tool in your toolkit!
Okay, enough of the lecture.  In looking through your code, you don't seem to really need the temp table #rpt, you just need to understand JOINs.  Hopefully this SQL will get you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT  vtl.ROW AS Ligne, vtl.DETAILCHANGEORDERCOU AS Lein, vtl.ACTIVITY AS Act, 
        vtl.DESCRIPTION AS Descr, vtl.AMOUNT AS MntBase, vtl.INVOICE AS MntFact,
        mac.CHANGEORDERNUMBER AS Modif, mac.DESCRIPTION AS Descr3, mac.CHANGEORDERCOUNTER AS Lien2,
        sum(jrap.payment) AS MntPy
FROM    cscomvtl AS vtl
        LEFT OUTER JOIN cscomac AS mac
            ON vtl.detailchangeordercou = mac.counter
        LEFT OUTER JOIN jraprvtl AS jrap
            ON vtl.row = jrap.poline
WHERE   projectnumber = @projet AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ponumber)) = @contrat
GROUP BY vtl.row, vtl.detailchangeordercou, vtl.activity, vtl.description, vtl.amount, 
         vtl.invoice, mac.changeordernumber, mac.description, mac.changeordercounter
```

You will likely have to tweak it to fit what you're trying to do in Excel, since you really didn't give much to go on there.